# Need to create shingles of term while searching in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have a question related to shingleAnalyzer, i want to create shingles of search term while feeding them to lucene for search

```
String term = "new york";
String[] fields = {"city", "city_desc"};
ShingleAnalyzerWrapper shingleWrapper = new ShingleAnalyzerWrapper(new StandardAnalyzerNew(Version.LUCENE_30, new File(GlobalData.GENERAL_STOPWORD_FILE)) , 5);

MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30,
                                                                  fields,
                                                                  shingleWrapper
                                                                 );
Query query = queryParser.parse(term); 
System.out.println("query : " + query.toString());
output: (city : new city_desc: new), (city : york city_desc : york)
```

Here the shingles of term are not able to generate, i want to have output something like this:

```
output : (city : new city_desc: new), (city : york city_desc : york), (city: new york, city_desc : new york)
```

Any idea? How can i do this?

Comment: can any body let me know how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can create query parser derived from MultiFieldQueryParser with overrided function getFieldQuery(String, String, boolean) where terms will be united in shingles and queries from these shingles will be created. if it is still actual I can get a sample code to do this